# Retrieve Runtime Component dimension in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs4

After a component is rendered, how can I get the width and height? I tried `.getWidth()` and `.getHeight()`, but it returns the values of config properties. It seems they are just the getters of `width` and `height` config options.

What I want is the width and height of component after its been shown or rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.getEl()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getEl) to retrieve top level element. And than use element's `getWidth` method:

```
var width = yourComponent.getEl().getWidth();
```

this will give you width of actual DOM element.

Comment: I didn't see it in docs. But When I run this code I saw this warning `[DEPRECATE][Ext.Button#getEl] getEl() is deprecated, please access the Component's element from the 'element' property instead`